# how to activate an excel workbook without using its name or at least part of it? the extracted sheet has a dynamic name

Tags: vba, excel

i'm almost done with my code to extract data from our company's server and paste it to a sheet that i already created that already hosts my code...the problem is that i wanna copy from this excel workbook that i opened from the server but the problem is that it has a dynamic name that is changed every time i retrieve it from the server. yet, the initial part of the workbook name does not change so is there a way where i can activate the workbook using only the unchanged name part? the constant part of the extracted workbook usually starts with BFUK then numbers, spaces and underscores then ends with .txt.xls "BFUK*****.txt.xls"

```
Sub test()

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "company website"
    logSite = "/logoff.do"
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate WebSite
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set unElement = .Document.getElementsByName("username")
        unElement.Item(0).Value = "username"
        Set pwElement = .Document.getElementsByName("password")
        pwElement.Item(0).Value = "password"
        .Document.forms(0).submit
        '.quit

        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop


        Set expElement = .Document.getElementsByClassName("nav__action dropdown-trigger js--tooltip")
        expElement(0).Click

        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .Document.getElementById("obb_EXPORT_EXCEL").Click

    End With

     application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04")) SendKeys "%O", True


    With objIE


      .Navigate logSite


>    End With

    Windows("sheet with the dynamic name.xls").Activate ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BC600").Copy

Windows("macro testing.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        [L:L].Select With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value End With

     End Sub
```

i really really need this guys so i would appreciate your help and i'm welcoming new ideas if that would get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a page [How to list all files in directory](http://software-solutions-online.com/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/). Once you have name of the file, you can compare it like this:

```
If fileName Like "BFUK*.txt.xls" Then
    Windows(fileName) ....
   'rest of your code...
End If
```

It will match names of files starting with "BFUK" and ending with ".txt.xls". Between can be any number of any characters.

Here's example macro:

```
Sub ListFilesMatchingPattern()

Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim path As String
'choose folder with your Excel files
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
path = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(path)
i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'open the Excel file if it matches pattern
    If objFile.Name Like "BFUK*txt.xls" Then
        'in your macro, you should do work on the file here
        Workbooks.Open (path & "\" & objFile.Name)
    End If
Next objFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @michal but i meant the workbook name sorry not a sheet in the same workbook. I edited my question now so you can recheck

Comment: thank you very much that was really helpful but still won't work with me. I'm aiming to have this code to run automatically every hour and the name will keep on changing and i won't be able to tell what is the file name unless i'm physically present infront of my workstation and keep on amending this code which will defeat the purpose. don't you agree?

Comment: But, you don't have to do anything. You have said that name of the file might change, but it will start with "BFUK" and end with ".txt.xls". This code will match only files, which name will match this pattern.

Comment: Turczyn thanks again my friend. i'm sure i'm doing something wrong as still the provided instructions aren't working considering that i'm new to VBA. i copied your code in a separate module just to test it. i saved the workbook on my desktop and was testing your code by giving it instructions to open this workbook but i was getting an error that there is no file with the name i provided.

Comment: can you show me with your code how to open this file given that it's saved on the desktop? i really appreciate your help @MichalTurczyn

Comment: @AliS Please try new macro... :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is the only way to get the data from the website. I'll figure something out

Comment: Did it work? What do you mean by getting data from website? I thought this is Excel question.

Comment: it is my friend. the records i'm trying to retrieve are from the company's secured server and they are stored there in an excel sheet. the retrieved workbook keeps on changing its name to the initials i mentioned above then the server adds the date and time of retrieval to the name and hence my problem. the code i wrote above helps in getting the workbook opened infront of me but can't copy any data from it since it is not active. you thankfully tried helping but still i can't get this opened workbook activated to write a code to copy data from it noting that i want this code to run hourly

Answer (score 0):

@Michal i found it and worked finally

```
> > Sub Tester()
> 
>    Const File_PATH As String = "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Ali\"
>    
> 
> Dim file As String

> 
> file = Dir$(File_PATH & "BFUK*" & ".xlsx")
> 
> If (Len(file) > 0) Then   Workbooks.Open(File_PATH & file).Activate
>       End If
> 
> End Sub
```

my only way then is to use `SendKeys "%S", True` to save the file in specific folder then the above code calls it up